# I need to convert this to javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert this to javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
});
```

Comment: can you share your HTML code

Comment: if metisMenu() is your custom function then create this function in some external javascript file which is accessible in every page

Comment: Why convert to javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

metisMenu is not a function ,then the object $ don't have the method , 
which means the related plugin for  metisMenu  is not working

Answer (score 0):

The code is in JavaScript itself but in order to use it you have to use it upon jQuery library using the metisMenu plugin.
For your reference go to the GitHub repo of [Metismenu](https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu)